# How to make sure a method is not called twice with the same argument?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Talking about JavaScript (or typescript), I'm trying to find a way to make sure that developers can't call a method multiple times with the same argument.

For example:

```
const foo = (name: string) => {}


foo("ABC") // ok

foo ("123") // ok

foo ("ABC") // should show an error in the IDE, as it was already called in the first interaction
```

Just to be clear, the error should be shown at "developing" (compilation?) time. I want developers to be aware of the mistake while coding, so the IDE should trigger the error.

How can I achieve it? Should I create a tslint error?
Please help

**Edit**: I may have not been 100% clear, but if no feature of JavaScript allows the above, then what also will do the job for me is probably a new custom tslint rule. If I'm not mistaken, rules can have a context where they can store some "cached" values. Hence, at development time, I should be able to see an error the same way we see other linting rules error in the IDE.

Can it be achieved? How can I create a new lint rules with a context that does the job?

Also, I don't mind if we do `foo(x)` and the rule is not able to detect what value x is, and I don't mind the order on which the function is called.

The rule has to be just smart enough to reckon simple cases where it can.

Comment: What if the call is `foo(x)`? How can you tell what the value of `x` will be?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a static annotation that can check that, as how often and in what order a function is called may depend on runtime information.

Comment: You can't do this in pure TS.  The only thing close to what you want is if `foo` is an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) but that wouldn't affect the apparent type of `foo` itself, so you'd need to work around by passing some kind of "token" to the function to record the state, as shown [in this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m07QRN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: What if user does `foo("ABC"); let x="ABC"; foo(x); let y="AB", foo(y+"C");` - you might be able to find a static code analysis tool (similar to ReSharper) but it's unlikely they have "don't call twice with same values" as a rule as it's definitely edge-case.   Easy enough to implement with a Set at runtime.

Comment: op here: I may have not been 100% clear, but if no feature of javascript allows the above, then what also will do the job for me is probably a new custom tslint rule. 
If I'm not mistaken, rules can have a context where they can store some "cached" values. Hence, at development time, I should be able to see an error, the same way we see other linting rules. Can it be achieved?

Also, I don't mind if we do foo(x) and the rule is not able to detect it, or about the order of the function called. The rules has to be just smart enough to reckon simple cases where it can.

Comment: "I'm trying to find a way to make sure that developers can't call a method multiple times with the same argument." This is strictly not possible to enforce statically in general, in no language, as this is an undecidable problem. If you restrict the function inputs to literals, of course, a static analysis tool can certainly do it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can statically do that, but you can throw an error at runtime in development only:

```
const usedNames = []

const foo = (name: string) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    if (usedNames.includes(name)) throw new Error(`Function already called with ${ name }.`)

    usedNames.push(name)
  }

  ...
}
```

The whole `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }` block [won't be present](https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/environment-variables/) in non-development builds.

Comment: If the language don't have the capability, what about having a linting rule instead?

Comment: @AlessandroCatania You can try with a custom ESLint rule, but those are static checks too, which have some drawbacks. For example, you can try @Dimava's TS solution, but you'll find that it doesn't work in some cases (e.g. if you call `.foo(someStringKey)`, where `someStringKey` is typed as `string`). My solution is also not perfect thought, as you might run the code and skip some invocations of `foo` that you actually wanted to catch. So, you might need both: runtime checks + static (TS or ESLint) checks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TypeScript or JavaScript doesn't have this kind of feature built-in. As far as I know, there's no mechanism within JavaScript or TypeScript that allows you to enforce a restriction at compile-time based on runtime values or usage. The languages simply aren't designed to keep track of this kind of usage.

Typically, a static type checker like TypeScript checks types based on static analysis, which doesn't involve executing or tracing the code. As a result, TypeScript can't provide checks that depend on the runtime behaviour of the code, like the order or frequency of function calls.

For catching these types of logical issues early, unit tests are often a better approach. You could write a test that asserts foo throws an error when called with the same argument twice, and then run your tests often during development. Alternatively, you could look into using a linter or static analysis tool that supports custom rules, but I don't think any existing tool can handle this specific case.

If you want to enforce a rule like this, your best bet might be to provide documentation or comments explaining the requirement, and to rely on developers to manually adhere to the requirement.

It's also possible that your use case could be better served with a different pattern or structure. If you find yourself needing to prevent developers from calling a method multiple times with the same argument, it might be worth considering a design that doesn't allow for that possibility in the first place

Comment: This is right. It's a very surprising pattern to encounter, even if it were possible to have static diagnostics, it's confusing to provide such an api. Probably an XY problem

Comment: This is almost what I thought, so I'm just looking for how to create a linting rule (for either eslint or tslint) and how to create that rule, which must have a context (cache all the values of the parameters for all the calls) available at static time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use chaining to list used arguments
https://tsplay.dev/WJpZrN

```
type conform<T, V, E> = T extends V ? T : { error: E }

type Chain<T> = {
  foo<V extends string>(
    name: conform<V, Exclude<V, T>, 'this argument is already used'>,
  ): Chain<T | V>
}

function chain(fn: (s: string) => void): Chain<never> {
  const c = {
    foo(s: string) {
      fn(s);
      return c;
    }
  };
  return c as any;
}

chain(console.log)
.foo('a') // ok
.foo('b') // ok
.foo('a') // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter
//   ~~~     of type '{ error: "this argument is already used"; }'.(2345)

let cc;
cc = chain(console.log)
cc = cc.foo('a'); // ok
cc = cc.foo('b'); // ok
cc = cc.foo('a'); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter
//          ~~~     of type '{ error: "this argument is already used"; }'.(2345)
```

Comment: This looks brilliant!!!!

The only catch is that the last line, which is how I want to use it, doesn't work (doesn't trigger the type error). Can you help me find the issue?


Also, Could it be done without chaining and perhaps using a combination of words too?

For example 

foo('a','b'); // ok
foo('a','c'); // ok
foo('a','b'); // ERROR